# CVS Version Tree plugin 1.7.2 for Eclipse photon(4.8) does not have extssh as connection Type

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse Photon(4.8) sts , I downloaded CVS versionTree 1.7.2, but the connection Type does not contain **extssh**. I am using MAC OS High sierra. Does anyone know how to resolve?
I tried downloading latest Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10.0) but when I search for CVS in Eclipse Marketplace, it does not return any result?
Any help appreciated

Comment: The CVS client for 2018-12 is in 'Help > Install New Software' choose the 2018-12 release site and search for CVS. I don't know if it has extsssh

Comment: Thanx..it worked..it had extssh too .